# How to check if image is available else download and display in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I am making an app which shows the cryptocurrency market but I want to show icons as well, so if I manually add the icons in the pubspec as assets and then display them, it's going to take a lot of time, about 10 hours. So I resolved to automation.

Can someone explain how to implement the following in Flutter?
 OR provide me with a better solution?

```
try {
 //get image from file
} catch ( exception ) {
 //download image
 //get image from file
}
```

Comment: Why does it take a long time if you add the image to pubspec?

Comment: Why do you want to download the image instead of displaying it directly?

Comment: Thomas, there are like 1500 currencies, adding the 50 of them took me about 2 hours, do the math. The will affect the size of my app as well and what if new currencies are made, then I will have to do the same thing for each new one. So isn't a good approach..

Comment: @H. Brooks Downloading 1500 images every time the app is opened, is also not a good approach.

Comment: Just to clarify.. that is why I was asking why you want to download them when you can load them from a url and caching them... I did not say you should download them every time you open your app, that would just be stupid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this situation you can cache the images using [Cached network image](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image) plugin

> A flutter library to show images from the internet and keep them in
>   the cache directory.

Comment: So basically it stores the images? So it won't  download the image everytime the user opens the app, right?

Comment: The cached files are stored in the temporary directory of the app. This means the OS can delete the files any time.but Various settings on how long to keep a file can be changed

Comment: Can you explain or refer to how I can do that?